# Book printing software

Tags: printing

I need a software for editing books for printing. It should have 1. adding numbers to pages 2. option to manage how an a5 book is printed (like rotating the text in each page so it can be the folded, cut, and put together with staples or a ribbon). Just some easy software for an amateur.

Context: I like reading from paper, not display, so considering I have a laser printer I want just to print some texts

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Until you add more specifics, consider to research "desktop publishing software" as such software directly addresses the references in your question.